# Old Data After Form submit on laravel

Tags: html, laravel

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="" >
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5">
        <label for="">From Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" id="from"   value="{{old('from')}}" required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <label for="">To Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" id="to" value="{{old('to')}}" required>
      </div>
        <div class="col2 pt-4 mt-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="search">
        </div>
     </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**I want my from data after submission. i am using get request to search data and refresh the page with new data with from date fields with old search data**

Comment: I'm using old data for rebuild form with "old" data after validation error occurred. Not sure if it working this way, try to dd($request) after submit and look, or just past data as var through controller.

Comment: What makes you think this isn't working?

Comment: you have to provide full blade code as well as controller method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood you want to show new data on your page while the **from** and **to** are from your previous request ?

Then why are you not returning the **to** and **from** with new data.

```
<input type="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="from" 
    id="from"   
    value= @if($from) "{{$from}}" @endif required>


<input type="date" 
    class="form-control" 
    name="to" 
    id="to"   
    value= @if($to) "{{$to}}" @endif required>
```

from controller return data that you want to return after applying the filters with the to and from